# vb.net combobox to return value of another column

Tags: vb.net

I have two comboboxes. The second one is dependant on the first. I then pass the selected values to a second form as objects. My code works perfectly up to here. But I also need to pass a third object to the second form (i.e. plaasnopass) based on the selection of the second combobox (i.e cmbPlaasnaam). This value however is in another column. My code below runs without errors , but the third value is not passed to the second form.

```
Public Class ParskaartjieKiesFrm

Dim obj As New Parskaartjies
Private Sub ParskaartjieKiesFrm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Wingrd13TableAdapter.Fill(Me.SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13)

    With CmbAliasnaam
        .BeginUpdate()
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

        Dim qry = From zc As SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13Row In SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13 _
                  Select zc.Aliasnaam Distinct Order By Aliasnaam
        For Each ALIASNAAM As String In qry
            .Items.Add(ALIASNAAM)
        Next
        .EndUpdate()

    End With

    With CmbPlaasnaam
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        .Enabled = False
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CmbAliasnaam_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbAliasnaam.SelectedIndexChanged

    obj.aliasnaampass = CmbAliasnaam.SelectedItem


    With CmbPlaasnaam
        .SelectedIndex = -1
        .Items.Clear()
        .Enabled = False

    End With


    If CmbAliasnaam.SelectedIndex > -1 Then

        CmbPlaasnaam.BeginUpdate()

        Dim Aliasnaam As String = CmbAliasnaam.Items(CmbAliasnaam.SelectedIndex).ToString

        Dim qry = From zc As SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13Row In SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13 _
                   Where zc.Aliasnaam = ALIASNAAM Select zc.Plaasnaam Distinct _
                   Order By Plaasnaam

        For Each plaasnaam As String In qry
            CmbPlaasnaam.Items.Add(plaasnaam)

        Next
        If CmbPlaasnaam.Items.Count > 0 Then
            CmbPlaasnaam.Enabled = True
        End If
        CmbPlaasnaam.EndUpdate()

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub CmbPlaasnaam_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbPlaasnaam.SelectedIndexChanged
    obj.plaasnaampass = CmbPlaasnaam.SelectedItem
    obj.plaasnopass = CmbAliasnaam.SelectedValue

    obj.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

How do I go about ?

Regards

Comment: What you mean by _in another column_? All your queries return only one column results. Do you have `DataGridView` from where you want take a value?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, I understood that you have combo box loaded from

```
select a from t
```

but this gives you single value, and you want to load

```
select a, b from t
```

and pass both values to next form.

It is helpful that you're using LINQ!! Modify it. But first declare new type

```
Public Class CboItem
    Public Property Display As String
    Public Property Value As String ' <-- any datatype
    ' ....  any number of properties here
End Class

 Dim qry = 
     (From zc As SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13Row 
         In SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.wingrd13 _
     Where zc.Aliasnaam = ALIASNAAM 
     Select New CboItem() With { .Display = zc.Plaasnaam, .Value = zs.[...] }).
     Distinct(function(item)...).OrderBy(function(item)...)

 CmbAliasnaam.DisplayMember = "Display"
 CmbAliasnaam.ValueMember = "Value"
 CmbAliasnaam.DataSource = qry.ToList()
```

Now you can pass to your form selected item or whatever you get out of it. for example

```
Dim item As CboItem = TryCast(CmbAliasnaam.SelectedItem, CboItem)
If item IsNot Nothing Then     
    frm.SetSelected(item.Display, item.Value, item.anyOtherProperty)
End If
' or
frm.SomeProperty = item
```

As you see, you can pass an object that you can store in combo box. It doesn't have to be string.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear. I have already passed the cmb.aliasnaam (I used obj.aliasnaampass = CmbAliasnaam.SelectedItem) as well as the obj.plaasnaampass = CmbPlaasnaam.SelectedItem. What I want to do is pass another column's value based on the selection from cmbplaasnaam. Thank you.